# Google Places API - search vicinity as a place

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I have this problem with Google Places API. I'm searching for "Guildhall" in Cambridge. It finds it exactly on maps: https://www.google.pl/maps/place/Guildhall,+Market+Hill,+Cambridge+CB2+3QJ,+Wielka+Brytania/@52.2046916,0.1193167,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x47d870bd9c1c0a5d:0x7228336bd9005dae

[image]

But places api doesn't return "Guildhall" as a result: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=52.2046916,0.1193167&rankby=distance&keyword=guildhall&sensor=true&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Is it possible to return results like "Guildhall" from Places API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the types of places you want returned by specifying the type:

See the documentation here; https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types

Then pass in the type option when creating your service;

```
var request = {
location: pyrmont,
radius: '500',
types: ['store'] // specify the types here 
};

service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
```

**UPDATE:**

I may have a solution for you:  You could try using the Geocode service from Google: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple

I have put it into a JS Fiddle for you to have a playaround with: http://jsfiddle.net/loanburger/1vhymg6m/

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you, but I want to get the vicinity as a result of searching. When I search for Guildhall I will get "Cambridge City Council" as a first result. But in reality the "The Guildhall, Market Hill, Cambridge" is a place/building with other places inside. So I'm wondering if it is possible to get exactly the example "The Guildhall, Market Hill, Cambridge" as a place with long and lat?

Comment: I understand.  I doubt Google maps will be that detailed.  Imaging having every building in the world with their businesses inside... It would be a nightmare to keep that updated accurately.

Comment: Thank you for the updated version of your answer :) It was very helpful :)